# RibbonGallery disabled in .net 4.6

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm creating an application using RibbonController in WPF.

It's working fine until i installed .net 4.6. Then my "RibbonGallery" is disabled state (Viewpoints Drop Down menu) . I tried to enable through Code also but no luck ;(.

```
<Custom:RibbonGallery SelectedValue="Entrancelobby" SelectedValuePath="Content" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" MaxHeight="500">
        <Custom:RibbonGalleryCategory Name="viewpointsList" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontSize="14">  
              <Custom:RibbonGalleryItem Content="Entrancelobby" Foreground="Black" />
              <Custom:RibbonGalleryItem Content="Entrancelobby 01" Foreground="Black"/> 
        <Custom:RibbonGalleryCategory>
</Custom:RibbonGallery>
```

See attachments
**No issue with 4.5**   [image: .Net 4.5 (Working)]

**.Net 4.6 (issue)** [image]

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is actually a bug in RibbonGallery that just happens to be exposed by new logic in 4.6.1.  The bug is that RG doesn't initialize its internal state correctly, so that if anyone calls CoerceValue(IsEnabledProperty) it coerces the value to false (i.e. disables the gallery).   For example, calling `ribbonGallery.IsEnabled = true;` will actually disable the RG (even in 4.0).

.Net 4.6.1 has better logic for propagating IsEnabled to descendants.  This logic ends up calling `ribbonGallery.CoerceValue(IsEnabledProperty)`, which disables the RG due to the bug.

There's a workaround:  Change the RG's Command.  This causes the RG to reset its internal state correctly, so that future coercions do the right thing.  For example:

```
ribbonGallery.Command = ApplicationCommands.Print;   // arbitrary command
ribbonGallery.Command = null;                        // don't keep the command
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming this is bug.     But to I don't understand how to solve this. Can you eloberat please

Comment: @satish_srg - RibbonGallery coerces IsEnabled to false if it has a command whose CanExecute is false.  If there's no command at all, that coercion shouldn't happen, but a faulty initialization causes it to happen anyway.   Setting the command to a non-null value cleans up the faulty state.  Setting it back to null discards the command you didn't really want, but now the RG is in a state where it will coerce IsEnabled correctly.

Comment: @moon - you have to set Command to a non-null value to fix the bug.  Then set it back to null to discard the command you didn't really want.

Comment: @SamBent-MSFT Do I have to do this for all the RibbonGalleries within my Ribbon?

Comment: @Vojtěch Dohnal  -  Yes, each RibbonGallery is initialized incorrectly, so each needs the workaround.

Comment: @SamBent-MSFT: do you know anything about plans to fix this bug?

Comment: Thankfullly RibbonGallery is not sealed, so I declared a subclass with just a ctor calling the above code, so all I needed to do was replace the type in the xaml, i.e. replace <RibbonGallery> with <MyRibbonGallery>

Comment: Is there a public bug tracking entry for this somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Disabled items in RibbonGallery is the same issue I’m getting, once IsEnabled is set to false I can’t enable again. This was working previously and noticed since updating to Net 4.6 on the PC. I’ve run an old program from a few years back without any recompilation and it suffers from the same fate. So even if Net 4.5 is targeted it will exhibit the same problem as it’s associated to the PC .Net installed. If the PC uses Windows 10 the Net framework can’t be rolled back to Net 4.5 as it uses 4.6 minimum right?

Tried setting the Command to null but this was unsuccessful. Tried Net 4.6.1 installed on PC and various combinations targeted but unsuccessful. For me I think I’ll rip out the Microsoft ribbon stuff which has always seemed a buggy afterthought costing me in development time.

Comment: I want to confirm, that bug is reproduced, when 4.6 is installed, even when project is targeting 4.5.